# why Break Apart Remove my test in flash cs6?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

I want to convert text to shape in flash cs6 AS3

when I click Break Apart then my text is removing.

Please advice me why?

Comment: what do you mean by **your text is removed**.

Comment: object deleted from my layer

Comment: can you print your screen and upload it so that we can have a look.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better enter your text in another software, like **word** or **paint**

Capture the screen (using PrtScr or PrintScreen or an utility)

Paste in your stage

Convert to symbol

Enter the symbol and then Break Apart!!

It will then be an Image and you can change it as you like!!

Good Luck!